# Sorting an associative array with numbers and text by value

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have an array of tags which contains keys and as value the number of occurences in a previous array:

```
Array ( [789] => 1 [sss] => 2 [aaa] => 3 [bbb] => 1 [taf] => 1 )
```

Now I would like to sort this array by number of occurence
I do this by using the following command:

```
array_multisort($array, SORT_DESC);
```

It works, but it changes the value of key "789" to 0 for some reason, so I get the following output:

```
Array ( [aaa] => 3 [sss] => 2 [taf] => 1 [0] => 1 [bbb] => 1 )
```

The values are retrieved from the database, when I change 789 to 789-, it works correctly.
So I assume the sorting goes wrong because 789 is a number.
Is there a way to achieve the desired result?
I tried converting 789 to a string but without result.

Comment: Just wondering, why sort twice in `array_multisort()`?

Comment: Good comment, I accidentally added it twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a function especially for this purpose (*ironically*) that preserves the keys while sorting in descending order, it's called **[arsort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php)**;

```
arsort($array);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [aaa] => 3
    [sss] => 2
    [taf] => 1
    [789] => 1
    [bbb] => 1
)
```

**[DEMO](https://eval.in/147034)**

The problem with `array_multisort()` as it states in the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php):

> Associative (string) keys will be maintained, but numeric keys will be
>   re-indexed.